# Featured image showing on admin 1x1

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image-resizing

I'm having some issues with the thumbnails in the admin section.

The featured image of the post is showing with 1px width and 1x height.

On the frontpage the thumbnail works perfectly but when i'm editing an entry it shows like this:

```
<img class="attachment-post-thumbnail" width="1" height="1" alt="19sushibar5" src="wp-content/uploads/2014/02/19sushibar5-1x1.jpg">
```

Is it possible to fix that in the admin side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove this ` width="1" height="1"`

Comment: But how? That's the problem that code is in the admin section when i'm editing a post

Comment: I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: @anulik I didn't find a solution for that